# How to identify intervel of time stamps in a column

Tags: mysql

I have table with 2 columns,we can see that Rowid(1-5) its 15 min interval & Rowid(6-10) its 1 hour interval , how to add a new column whichn shows the time intervals.

```
Rowid          Date             Value
1      01-Nov-16 00:00:00       716
2      01-Nov-16 00:15:00       716
3      01-Nov-16 00:15:00       716
4      01-Nov-16 00:45:00       717
5      01-Nov-16 01:00:00       716

6      01-Nov-16 01:00:00       34
7      01-Nov-16 02:00:00       66
8      01-Nov-16 03:00:00       717
9      01-Nov-16 04:00:00       717
10     01-Nov-16 05:00:00       717
```

O/P :

```
Rowid          Date           Value      Interval_gap
1      01-Nov-16 00:00:00      716           15 mins
2      01-Nov-16 00:15:00      716           15 mins
3      01-Nov-16 00:15:00      716           15 mins
4      01-Nov-16 00:45:00      717           15 mins
5      01-Nov-16 01:00:00      716           15 mins

6      01-Nov-16 01:00:00      34            1 hour
7      01-Nov-16 02:00:00      66            1 hour
8      01-Nov-16 03:00:00      717           1 hour
9      01-Nov-16 04:00:00      717           1 hour
10     01-Nov-16 05:00:00      717           1 hour
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] and format your question and show what you tried

Comment: try formatting your question's data and results so it makes more sense to readers. are there multiple rows of data nd output - hard to tell.

Comment: look at the toolbar above the edit box, there are 2 braces {} highlight some text you want to present as "code" and it will do that for you. simple. You already had the data in rows, all you then needed was the formatting.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an "answer" but I need formatting to make a point:

Please check your expected result. I assume "value" means the rows are related, and that for any sequence the first row cannot produce a result 
e.g.

```
Rowid          Date           Value      Interval_gap
1      01-Nov-16 00:00:00      716           NULL     << nothing prior to this row, so no calculation
2      01-Nov-16 00:15:00      716           15 mins
3      01-Nov-16 00:15:00      716           0 mins
5      01-Nov-16 01:00:00      716           45 mins

6      01-Nov-16 01:00:00      34            NULL     << nothing prior to this row, so no calculation

7      01-Nov-16 02:00:00      66            NULL     << nothing prior to this row, so no calculation

4      01-Nov-16 00:45:00      717           NULL     << nothing prior to this row, so no calculation
8      01-Nov-16 03:00:00      717           2 Hours 45 mins
9      01-Nov-16 04:00:00      717           1 hour
10     01-Nov-16 05:00:00      717           1 hour
```

Round 2

```
Rowid          Date           Value      Interval_gap  Named
1      01-Nov-16 00:00:00      716           NULL      ABC
2      01-Nov-16 00:15:00      716           15 mins   ABC
3      01-Nov-16 00:15:00      716           15 mins   ABC
4      01-Nov-16 00:45:00      717           15 mins   ABC
5      01-Nov-16 01:00:00      716           15 mins   ABC

6      01-Nov-16 01:00:00      34            NULL      XYZ
7      01-Nov-16 02:00:00      66            1 hour    XYZ
8      01-Nov-16 03:00:00      717           1 hour    XYZ
9      01-Nov-16 04:00:00      717           1 hour    XYZ
10     01-Nov-16 05:00:00      717           1 hour    XYZ
```

Comment: hi @Used_by_already ,it doesnt mean value are row related , plz consider rowid(1-5) as named As "ABC" & rowid(6-10) as "XYZ"

Comment: fine, consider them named, but WHERE? How are we supposed to guess that is the case. We cannot read your mind (or your question), so place the "names" into he sample data and then also re-consider that the first for 5 rows of data you can only calclate 4 intervals (as you need to compare 2 rows for each interval). Edit you answer - do not add more comments here. I will eventually delete this "answer" and the comments will go also.